# Where is my misunderstanding/mistake in calculation about maximum entropy

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, maximum-entropy

I am looking through the book *Philosophy of Science : Entropy and Uncertainty* by

Teddy Seidenfeld and have some questions.

He talks about the basic dice example, where by you have a fair six sided die.

The most basic example is for shannon entropy defined as

$ \epsilon (p)=-\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i}log(p_{i})$

and if we have our only constraint being that it must be a true distribution ie sum to 1, then by using that as our constraint

we solve and set equal to zero for each $i$, $$\frac{\partial }{\partial pi}[-\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i}log(p_{i})+\lambda(\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i}-1)]=0$$ evaluated at $p_{i}^{*}$

Ie for that basic example, we would get

$\lambda=1+log(p_{1}^{*})$

$\lambda=1+log(p_{2}^{*})$

$\lambda=1+log(p_{3}^{*})$

and so forth,

which clearly implies that all the $p^{*} $are equal and hence we have a uniform distribution. So that is clear.

I tried to do the same with the example that the expected value of the top of the die was 3.5. Intuitively we can see it will be uniform with each $p_{i}=\frac{1}{6}$

but I want to see where I go wrong in the following.

So we have the same constraint, but now we have an additional constraint, ie

$p_{1}+2p_{2}+3p_{3}+4p_{4}+5p_{5}+6p_{6}-3.5=0$

and

$p_{1}+p_{2}+p_{3}+p_{4}+p_{5}+p_{6}-1=0$

So I thought I could combine this into one constraint ie

$2p_{1}+3p_{2}+4p_{3}+5p_{4}+6p_{5}+7p_{6}-4.5=0$

But then repeating the above would give

$2\lambda=1+log(p_{1}^{*})$

$3\lambda=1+log(p_{2}^{*})$

and so forth, which could only imply uniform if $\lambda=0$

But I think I am missing something important. Like a misunderstanding of the lagrange multipliers or how I am attempting to apply them.

If I try it using two Lagrange multipliers I still get issues,

ie,

$log(p_{1})=\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}-1$

$log(p_{2})=\lambda_{1}+2\lambda_{2}-1$

.
.
.
$log(p_{6})=\lambda_{1}+6\lambda_{2}-1$

Which would only be uniform if $\lambda_{2}=0$

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The way you are combining the two constraints won't work; to see this, consider the two constraints $x_1=0$, $x_2 = 0$.  Adding them gives $x_1 + x_2 = 0$, a very different constraint.  Try instead solving the second one for $p_6$, then substituting the expression for $p_6$ into the first one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good to remember now that you can't combine constraints. Are you saying solve $p_{6}$ in terms of the others and then use that as a constraint? Because I must be misunderstanding what you mean, because if I do that, I would get $1+log(p_{1}=\lambda(1+(1/6)) , 1+log(p_{2})=\lambda(1+(2/6))$

Comment: I see what's happening; basically, your second constraint is satisfied by the solution to the problem with only the first constraint, so at the optimum it's redundant and can be ignored.  Writing out how you know the equal-probability solution is the right one is something I don't have the time to do right now, I'm afraid.

Comment: @jbowman Thats okay. thanks for trying. I think I figured it out. Once I have it in the form of the bottom, I then have to plug back in to my original constraints and solve for the $\lambda$ , using geometric series and such.

Comment: Since you solved it yourself, please post that as an answer (in the answer box), so this does not linger on as unsolved!